# In Python 3, why do I get "TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable" (or see a strange result instead of a list)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tagged file in the format token/tag and I try a function that returns a tuple with words from a (word,tag) list.

```
def text_from_tagged_ngram(ngram): 
    if type(ngram) == tuple:
        return ngram[0]
    return " ".join(zip(*ngram)[0]) # zip(*ngram)[0] returns a tuple with words from a (word,tag) list
```

In python 2.7 it worked well, but in python 3.4 it gives an error on the last line which says `TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable`.
Why did it stop working? How can I fix this?

---

<sub>Several other things changed from Python 2 to Python 3 in a parallel manner; see [How to use filter, map, and reduce in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638898).</sub>

Answer (score 165, accepted):

In Python 2, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) returned a list. In Python 3, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns an iterable object. But you can make it into a list just by calling [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), as in:

```
list(zip(...))
```

In this case, that would be:

```
list(zip(*ngram))
```

With a list, you can use indexing:

```
items = list(zip(*ngram))
...
items[0]
```

etc.

But if you only need the first element, then you don't strictly need a list. You could just use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next).

In this case, that would be:

```
next(zip(*ngram))
```

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x, [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) returns a special sort of iterator, not a list. The documentation explains:

> `zip()` is lazy: The elements won’t be processed until the iterable is iterated on, e.g. by a for loop or by wrapping in a `list`.

This entails that it can't be indexed, so old code that attempts to index or slice the result of a `zip` will fail with a `TypeError`. Simply passing the result to `list` produces a list, which can be used as it was in 2.x.

It also entails that [iterating over the `zip` result a second time will not find any elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726). Thus, if the data needs to be reused, create a list *once* and reuse the list - trying to create it again will make an empty list:

```
>>> example = zip('flying', 'circus')
>>> list(example)
[('f', 'c'), ('l', 'i'), ('y', 'r'), ('i', 'c'), ('n', 'u'), ('g', 's')]
>>> list(example)
[]
```

This iterator is implemented as an instance of a class...

```
>>> example = zip('flying', 'circus')
>>> example
<zip object at 0x7f76d8365540>
>>> type(example)
<class 'zip'>
>>> type(zip)
<class 'type'>
```

... which is built-in:

```
>>> class example(int, zip): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
>>> # and that isn't caused by __slots__ either:
>>> zip.__slots__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'zip' has no attribute '__slots__'
```

(See also: [TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48136025), [Cannot inherit from multiple classes defining __slots__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857515))

The key advantage of this is that it saves memory, and allows for short-circuiting when the inputs are also lazy. For example, corresponding lines of two large input text files can be `zip`ped together and iterated, without reading the entire files into memory:

```
with open('foo.txt') as f, open('bar.txt') as g:
    for foo_line, bar_line in zip(f, g):
        print(f'{foo_line:.38} {bar_line:.38}')
        if foo_line == bar_line:
            print('^ found the first match ^'.center(78))
            break
```