# TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, defaultdict

I wanted to create a class out of two: `collections.OrderedDict` and `collections.DefaultDict`. So that I can get an ordered dictionary and have a default value for non existing keys being accessed. Whats are some ways to do this?

My solution was to create another class around the 2 classes I stated above. This makes an error due to a method in each class having the same name I think?

```
from collections import defaultdict, OrderedDict
class owndic(OrderedDict, defaultdict):
    pass
```

producing

```
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Cheers!

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I can't reproduce the error on Python 3.4.2

Comment: Regardless of the cause of your `TypeError` if you want to use both functionalities you better use `OrderedDict` and it's `setdefault()` attribute which has a same functionality as `defaultdict`.

Comment: The error seems to be because both `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict` inherit from built-in `dict` type (their only base type) and this not allowed in python.

Comment: Its python 3 in hackerrank - Doesn't say the exact version. Lovely I will try `setdefault` thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`Instance lay-out conflict` is a fancy way of saying that you're trying to inherit from multiple--in this case built-in--types that cannot cooperate with each other quite well. More technically these classes have conflict in functionality of their common attributes.

In this case both `OrderedDict` and `defaultdict` are two dictionary-like types with their own unique `__setitem__` attributes and also different ways of handling the keys and values.

At C level this error happens when the [`best_base`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5b0e9db1b9698e6ffc43ae41cf3a22ca5a6ba6/Objects/typeobject.c#L2007) function fails to calculate the best base amongst multiple base classes. There are multiple other reasons that can cause this function fail to calculate the best base or winner among other bases but in this case the error occurs when neither of following conditions happen. `winner` is not None, `winner` is not a subtype of `candidate`<sup>*</sup>, `candidate` is not a subtype of `winner`.

```
candidate = solid_base(base_i);
if (winner == NULL) {
    winner = candidate;
    base = base_i;
}
else if (PyType_IsSubtype(winner, candidate))
    ;
else if (PyType_IsSubtype(candidate, winner)) {
    winner = candidate;
    base = base_i;
}
else {
    PyErr_SetString(
        PyExc_TypeError,
        "multiple bases have "
        "instance lay-out conflict");
    return NULL;

}
```

However, if you want to benefit from both `defaultdict()` and `OrderedDict()`'s functionalities, you can simply use an `OrderedDict` and its built-in `setdefault` attribute.

Here is an example:

```
In [13]: d = OrderedDict()

In [14]: for i, j in enumerate(['k', 'r', 'k', 'j', 'j', 't']):
             d.setdefault(j, []).append(i)
   ....:     

In [15]: d
Out[15]: OrderedDict([('k', [0, 2]), ('r', [1]), ('j', [3, 4]), ('t', [5])])
```

---

<sub>* `candidate` is the solid base of `base_i`,one of the bases passed to the class caller, that is calculated using [`solid_base`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5b0e9db1b9698e6ffc43ae41cf3a22ca5a6ba6/Objects/typeobject.c#L2086) function.</sub>

Comment: I've got this when I started to introduce `__slots__` to `pypdf`

Comment: Got into this issue when I tried to give, `class D(C,B)` and `class C(A)` and `class B(A)` all `__slots__` including `class A`. I could resolve it by changing the `mro` so that it turned to be `class D(C)` and `class C(B)` and `class B(A)`. This way I was able to implement `__slots__` or I had to drop `__slots__` in `class A`.