# Python 3.6 - TypeError: 'zip' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, python-3.6

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431390/typeerror-zip-object-is-not-subscriptable). However, the solution of transforming the zip from a iterable object to a list or tuple did not work for me, and I still get the same error.

My goal is to name a portion of my `outFeatureClass` after the `monthyear` list used in my `zip` funciton.
Does anyone know why this will not work for me in Python 3.6?

Here is my code, and my problem is occurring on the last line:

```
    import arcpy
    import datetime 
    import time
    from datetime import timedelta

    # Set environment settings
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps6.gdb"

    #Declare variables
    fc = 'Open_GoHealth_Centers'
    fields = ['USER_market_id','USER_GoHealth_ID','USER_GoHealth_Center_Name','USER_Opening_Date', 'USER_MonthsSinceFHOpening']
    fieldname = 'USER_market_id'

    # Set Markets to loop through
    markets = [1000]

    myranges = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39]#[(1,3)]#,(1,5)]
    #print (myranges)
    monthyear = ['Nov2014','Dec2014','Jan2015','Feb2015','Mar2015','Apr2015','May2015','Jun2015','Jul2015','Aug2015','Sep2015','Oct2015','Nov2015','Dec2015','Jan2016','Feb2016','Mar2016','Apr2016','May2016','Jun2016','Jul2016','Aug2016','Sep2016','Oct2016','Nov2016','Dec2016','Jan2017','Feb2017','Mar2017','Apr2017','May2017','Jun2017','Jul2017','Aug2017','Sep2017','Oct2017','Nov2017','Dec2017','Jan2018','Feb2018','Mar2018','Apr2018','May2018','Jun2018','Jul2018','Aug2018','Sep2018','Oct2018','Nov2018','Dec2018','Jan2019','Feb2019','Mar2019','Apr2019','May2019','Jun2019','Jul2019','Aug2019','Sep2019','Oct2019','Nov2019','Dec2019','Jan2020','Feb2020','Mar2020','Apr2020','May2020','Jun2020','Jul2020','Aug2020','Sep2020','Oct2020','Nov2020','Dec2020','Jan2021','Feb2021','Mar2021','Apr2021','May2021','Jun2021','Jul2021','Aug2021','Sep2021','Oct2021','Nov2021','Dec2021','Jan2022','Feb2022','Mar2022','Apr2022','May2022','Jun2022','Jul2022','Aug2022','Sep2022','Oct2022','Nov2022','Dec2022','Jan2023','Feb2023','Mar2023','Apr2023','May2023','Jun2023','Jul2023','Aug2023','Sep2023','Oct2023','Nov2023','Dec2023','Jan2024','Feb2024','Mar2024','Apr2024','May2024','Jun2024','Jul2024','Aug2024','Sep2024','Oct2024','Nov2024','Dec2024','Jan2025','Feb2025','Mar2025','Apr2025','May2025','Jun2025','Jul2025','Aug2025','Sep2025','Oct2025','Nov2025','Dec2025']
    monthname = ['November', 'December', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December','January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December',]
    monthabbr = ['Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec','Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
    year = [2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,2019,   2019,   2019,   2019,   2019,   2019,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,   2020,   2020,   2020,2020,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,2021,   2021,   2021,   2021,   2021,   2021,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,   2022,   2022,   2022,   2022,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,2023,   2023,   2023,   2023,   2023,2024,2024,2024,2024,2024,2024,2024,2024,   2024,   2024,   2024,   2024,2025,2025,2025,2025,2025,2025,2025,2025,   2025,   2025,   2025,   2025]

    month_description = zip(myranges,monthyear,monthname,monthabbr,year)
    #print(list(month_description))
    month_descr = list(month_description)

    sqlclause = (None, 'Order By USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')

    for market in markets:
        print (market)

        #Define WHERE clause statement
        whereclause = """{} = """.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, fieldname)) + str(market)
    #    print (whereclause)
        for myrange in myranges:
            print (myrange)

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table = fc, field_names = fields, where_clause=whereclause, sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY USER_market_id, USER_GoHealth_ID')) as cursor:
                            #Loop through each row established in cursor
                            for row in (cursor):
                                # Set local variables for the FeatureClasstoFeatureClass tool
                                inFeatures = "PatientVisitsGeocoded"
                                outLocation = r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps6.gdb"
                                outFeatureClass = "PatientVisits{0}_{1}_{2}".format(row[0], row[2], month_descr[1])
```

Comment: ...but you haven't converted the zip to a list

Comment: @myrtlecat I thought `list(zip(month_description))` would convert it to a list?

Comment: A. it would, but in your code you have `month_description = zip(myranges,monthyear,monthname,monthabbr,year)` without any call to `list`. The `print(list(month_description))` on the next line does not change `month_description` to a list, it creates a new copy, converts the copy to a list, prints it, and then throws it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you create a zip and assign it to `month_description`:

```
month_description = zip(myranges,monthyear,monthname,monthabbr,year)
```

Then later on you apply `zip` again on an object that is inside an interable, not a list (`list()` you apply theoretically would convert immediate `zip` object to a list but not the one that you assigned to to `month_description` earlier. The actual reason for the exception is that you attempt to iterate to the zip object using `[0]`):

```
outFeatureClass = "PatientVisits{0}_{1}_{2}".format(row[0], row[2], list(zip(month_description[1])))
```