# code equivalent in Python 3 for zip related statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

What would be the code equivalent for the following in Python 3?

```
def spiral_matrix(m):
    result = []
    while len(m) > 0:
        result += m[0]
        m = zip(*m[1:len(m)])[::-1]
    return result
```

the error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/mona/Python_Playground/spiral_matrix.py", line 38, in <module>
    print(spiral_matrix(b))
  File "/Users/mona/Python_Playground/spiral_matrix.py", line 34, in spiral_matrix
    m = zip(*m[1:len(m)])[::-1]
```

Comment: You've missed out the actual error message; making a guess on what it might be for assumed input (also not provided) if you searched for it you'd get e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431390/typeerror-zip-object-is-not-subscriptable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
m = list(zip(*m[1:len(m)]))[::-1]
```

In Python 3, *zip()* return an iterator.  Wrapping it in *list()* will run the iterator to create list, giving the same behavior as Python 2.